# How to iterate through all column headers in jQuery Datatables

Tags: jquery, datatables, iterator, datatables-1.10, jquery-datatables-editor

I am using a "fnDrawCallback" in Datatables to get the all column headers names () for that I am using the code below

```js
"fnDrawCallback": function () {
    table.column().every( function () {
        var data = this.data();
        var title = table.columns().header();

        console.log($(title).html());
    } );
```

I can get the column header name for first column . I want to know how can I iterate through all columns in table and get all the header () name?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest way I know to do this is with some jQuery inside the [`drawCallback`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/drawCallback) option:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example').DataTable( {

      "drawCallback": function ( settings ) {
        $('#example thead tr th').each(function() {
          console.log( $(this).html() );
        }); 
      }

    } );

  } );

</script>
```

I am using the more recent `drawCallback`, not the older legacy `fnDrawCallback` (but both do work).

---

*Just to note*: In your question, you are using `table.column().every( function () {...}`. I can't see how you are defining your `table` variable, in your example. So if my suggested approach is not suitable, perhaps you can edit your question to show the context in which you are using `fnDrawCallback`.

---

**Update**

If you want to hide one or more columns based on the names of the column headings, then you can take the above code and modify it as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {

    $('#example').DataTable( {

      "drawCallback": function ( settings ) {
        var tbl = $('#example').DataTable();

        var colIndex = 0;
        $('#example thead tr th').each(function() {
          var colHeading = $(this).html();
          if (colHeading === 'Office' || colHeading === 'Age') {
            tbl.columns( colIndex ).visible( false );
          }
          colIndex += 1;
        }); 
      }

    } );

  } );

</script>
```

In the above example, I have a table where the "Office" and "Age" columns are hidden when the table is drawn.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I was looking for. Can you please have look at the answer I posted

Answer (score 0):

```
  var table = $('#contracts').DataTable( {
  

  "drawCallback": function ( settings ) {


                    $('#contracts thead tr th').each(function() {

        // var title = table.column().th();
        // table.column( this ).column;
            
           var head = $(this).text();
                      console.log(head);

       
            if ($(this).text() == "" ) {
                                            console.log("abc");

                                 table.column().visible(false);

                            }

                             else  {
                          
                                  table.column().visible( true );
                        
                          
                  }
        }); 
      }
});
```

@andrewjames it works as expected but it doesn't hide columns based on the condition. It just hides the first column in table

Comment: I am not sure I understand the code you have provided here - it will not run. It will throw a JavaScript error at the `"drawCallback": function ( settings ) {` line because that line is not inside the DataTable definition. However, I have tried to provide some notes in my answer - I hope they help.

Comment: More generally, instead of asking a follow-on question by writing an answer, you should write a brand new question instead (or edit your question).

Comment: @andrewjames absolutely! you are right , it was mistake from my side, it has to be inside datatable definition.  Thanks for the help